# When I'm turning on my internet connection(3g) on galaxy S PLUS, it starts to screen shot itself

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

When I'm turning on my internet connection via 3G on Galaxy S+, it starts to screen shot itself - aproximately 8 times a minute. And this resulted in all my applications shutting down after 3 seconds. And all of this happens, only when I'm in my flat, only in my house, every day.

Comment: That's a hard one, needs more info. Can you send some  [logs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat)?

Comment: Hardware keys sticking? Something triggering it? As for screenshotting itself, is in Android 4 (ICS upwards) Power + Vol Down in combination...